# Sum row with same id (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sum

( the last )I would like to  sum  row with the same user_id ( for the column ponderation, I dont need to have other column , only user_id and ponderation)

[image]

My query

```
SELECT  students_group.user_id,scores.result ,exam.name,exam.ponderation,exam.id, (scores.result * exam.ponderation) / totpond.totalpond as ponderation
from (
select sum(exam.ponderation)  as totalpond from scores
left join exam on exam.id = scores.exam_id
left join teacher_group on teacher_group.id = exam.teacher_group_id
left join groups on  groups.id = teacher_group.group_school_id
left join students_group on students_group.user_id = scores.user_id
where teacher_group.id = 54
group by students_group.user_id

 ) as totpond,scores
left join exam on exam.id = scores.exam_id
left join teacher_group on teacher_group.id = exam.teacher_group_id
left join groups on  groups.id = teacher_group.group_school_id
left join students_group on students_group.user_id = scores.user_id

where teacher_group.id = 54
group by scores.id
order by students_group.user_id
```

Is it to possible to do that with my query or need to use php ?  Can someone help me please ?  thx  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessary you would just need to add the summation of that field in the query:

```
 SELECT 
       tmp.user_id,
       SUM(tmp.ponderation) as total_ponderation,
       SUM(tmp.aggregate_ponderation) as ponderation
    FROM
    (
    SELECT  students_group.user_id,scores.result ,exam.name,exam.ponderation,exam.id, (scores.result * exam.ponderation) / totpond.totalpond as aggregate_ponderation
    from (
    select sum(exam.ponderation)  as totalpond from scores
    left join exam on exam.id = scores.exam_id
    left join teacher_group on teacher_group.id = exam.teacher_group_id
    left join groups on  groups.id = teacher_group.group_school_id
    left join students_group on students_group.user_id = scores.user_id
    where teacher_group.id = 54
    group by students_group.user_id

     ) as totpond,scores
    left join exam on exam.id = scores.exam_id
    left join teacher_group on teacher_group.id = exam.teacher_group_id
    left join groups on  groups.id = teacher_group.group_school_id
    left join students_group on students_group.user_id = scores.user_id

    where teacher_group.id = 54
    group by scores.id
    ) tmp
    GROUP BY
      tmp.user_id
```

Comment: kk thx but , I need to put the result of total_ponderation you just add  and put that in totpond.totalpond (in my formula (scores.result * exam.ponderation) / totpond.totalpond as aggregate_ponderation )

Comment: I will accept you're question and I will post an other question  on stack for my next part. Thx for you're help!!  =)

Answer (score 1):

You could use your current query as a subquery and aggregate the results from that like so:

```
 SELECT 
       tmp.user_id,
       SUM(tmp.aggregate_ponderation) as ponderation
    FROM
    (
    SELECT  students_group.user_id,scores.result ,exam.name,exam.ponderation,exam.id, (scores.result * exam.ponderation) / totpond.totalpond as aggregate_ponderation
    from (
    select sum(exam.ponderation)  as totalpond from scores
    left join exam on exam.id = scores.exam_id
    left join teacher_group on teacher_group.id = exam.teacher_group_id
    left join groups on  groups.id = teacher_group.group_school_id
    left join students_group on students_group.user_id = scores.user_id
    where teacher_group.id = 54
    group by students_group.user_id

     ) as totpond,scores
    left join exam on exam.id = scores.exam_id
    left join teacher_group on teacher_group.id = exam.teacher_group_id
    left join groups on  groups.id = teacher_group.group_school_id
    left join students_group on students_group.user_id = scores.user_id

    where teacher_group.id = 54
    group by scores.id
    ) tmp
    GROUP BY
      tmp.user_id
```

Comment: .... oh.... just one litle question... my totalpond  wont work , I need for example to sum  ponderation field for the same user _id  (for example ,  20 + 15 for user_id  82 ) , I need to do an other subquery ?